# Geometry nodes: Control z axis of items individually and simulatneously

Tags: geometry-nodes, parent, mathematics

This post might sound wierd but here me out.
I am working on an exercise for myself creating functional horizontal blinds from geometry nodes. I would like them to work just like in real life. As you open up the blinds they start to stack ontop of each other. See examples below:

[image]

[image]

I will have the Blend file below.  How would I start to achieve this result? I know I would need to realize each of the blind instances But how do I move the bottom element up by itself untill it makes contact with the other blind where they then move together? How would I start something like that?

[image]

Comment: I found a solution to your problem, here is a solution, maybe some values ​will have to be replaced or added https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYLHA.png it looks like this Value 1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYSi1.png value 0 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Ico.png

Answer (score 0):

There a many ways to approach this **Blinds problem**.
(You can skip to the Geometry Node solution which is on the bottom of the post)

The fastest way to solve it is using Object Constraints. ***No Geo Nodes required.*** Recommended if you know the correct parameters to set up the blinds, like size and various heights. You could always adjust the values but it quickly gets tedious entering values for each object in the Constraint panels. So you have to be prepared.

Here is how it works in brief:

Each slat object is positioned above the previous one with maximum distance  between each slant (i.e when the blinds are down).
Each slat object has the following constraints.

**Limit Distance** - with Target object the slat element beneath it.

**Floor** - with Target object the slat element beneath it.

The first constraint "pulls" the object if too far from the target
The second constraint always keeps the object above the target,

Here is a screenshot of the settings:[image]

The only exception makes the bottom slat which only has **Limit Location constraint** to prevent it from going too far down or up:

[image]

Now by moving the bottom slant up and down you get the desired effect:

[image].

**The geeky way to solve the Blinds is via Geometry Nodes. This allows quicker settings but also longer time for making a user friendly design.**

Quick explanation:
You need two empties to control the height of the blinds (**Bottom** and **Top**) and one empty to control the opening and closing - **Slider**.
You can set the desired amount of slats via ***Number of Slats***.

A Mesh Line is created with the same number of points which you can use to instance your Slant object. You can adjust the height of the object in the Modifiers tab.
The most important operations are framed with a brief explanation text about their function. Avery useful node in the solution is the [Accumulate Field Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/field/accumulate_field.html).

There are no constraints set on the control objects so you should expect unpredictable results if pushed too far or towards unaccounted direction.
Here are screenshots of the node setup in case the blend file attached on the bottom no longer exists:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Demo of the modifier:

[image]

Lastly, the blend file with both solutions as separate collections.

[image]